# CSS minimum width on overlay with fixed position that is centered

Tags: css, height, position, center, fixed

I have a page where the content is positioned in the center of the page using margin:auto and I want to add a background that is centered the same way but because of the background doesn't appear when I scroll down I have resorted to using position:fixed which nicely does the trick.

However, positioning it centrally the same way as the content is proving a huge challenge because playing with left:x% and margin-left:-y% is a nightmare and never quite works well that all screen resolutions.

The markup is simple:

```
<div id="main" class="container">   
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div id="content"></div> 
</div>
```

You can see the site [HERE](http://www.psgardensltd.co.uk/new/)

The BEST CSS configuration I came up with is this:

```
.overlay
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; /* These positions makes sure that the overlay */
  bottom: 0;  /* will cover the entire parent */
  left: 0;
  width: 72%;
  margin-left:14%;
  height:100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.45;
  -moz-opacity: 0.45; /* older Gecko-based browsers */
  filter:alpha(opacity=45); /* For IE6&7 */
}
```

I've tried many combinations but the background always resized differently than the content and I would want it to stay in place.
Position:absolute with margin:auto works perfectly well except when you scroll down.

The above configuration works nicely except the "min-width". If I could get it to stop minimizing after a certain point, this would be perfect.

Many thanks in advance if you have a solution to this

Answer (score 2):

you could use `background-attachment: fixed` for your background, instead of using empty markup for styling purpose. in this way you will see it even when you're scrolling down the page.

Comment: background-attachment: fixed causes some dramatic mess ups on the entire page... perhaps I'm not using it right but it pushes the content UNDER the background...

Comment: background-attachment has no effect on the content inside the element. it cannot push the elements or text nested in that element. remove useless markup and place that background under your text along with `background-position`

Comment: Right I thought you meant background-attachment: fixed instead of position:fixed. If I have both in, there is no difference. 
Min-width problem still there. Thanks

Comment: please, set up a fiddle with your real background image and explain how you have to align it

Comment: The real background image takes up the entire page 100% width and height and that works fine.
The overlay is just full height centered column that should stay centered as the page resizes. That works too, except from the min width.

Comment: Still no answer to this? I added the site to show you what I'm trying to achieve